# Start inparaenum-numeration with another letter than "a)"

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate, counters, paralist

How can I start `\begin{inparaenum}` with an arbitrary letter (other than a)) after a break in the inparaenum-environment. I would like to let a new inparaenum-environment be related to the end of the earlier one.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage{paralist}                                       
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Working with logarithms}: 

    \NumTabs{3}
    \begin{inparaenum}[a)]
    Calculate the following

    \item $\ln 1 = $ 
    \tab \item $\ln e = $ 
    \tab \item $\ln \frac{1}{e} = $
    \end{inparaenum} 

    Express the following in terms of $\ln 2$: 

    \NumTabs{3}
    \begin{inparaenum}[d)]
    \item $\ln 4$ 
    \tab \item $\ln \sqrt[3]{2^5}$ 
    \tab \item $\ln \frac{1}{16} $
    \end{inparaenum} 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to let the second row start with d instead of using d in all positions? Thank you very much :)

[image]

Comment: The `\begin{inparamenum}[d)]` is wrong and the compiler complains about it ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the number by hand; since it's a second level list, you have to set `enumii`.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage{paralist}                                       
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Working with logarithms}: 

    \NumTabs{3}
    \begin{inparaenum}[a)]
    Calculate the following

    \item $\ln 1 = $ 
    \tab \item $\ln e = $ 
    \tab \item $\ln \frac{1}{e} = $
    \end{inparaenum} 

    Express the following in terms of $\ln 2$: 

    \NumTabs{3}
    \begin{inparaenum}[a)]\setcounter{enumii}{3}
    \item $\ln 4$ 
    \tab \item $\ln \sqrt[3]{2^5}$ 
    \tab \item $\ln \frac{1}{16} $
    \end{inparaenum} 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use, instead, `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\NumTabs{3}
\item \textbf{Working with logarithms}:

Calculate the following\\[\medskipamount]
  \begin{enumerate*}[label=\alph*),itemjoin=\tab,before={}]
  \item $\ln 1 = $ 
  \item $\ln e = $ 
  \item $\ln \frac{1}{e} = $
  \end{enumerate*}

Express the following in terms of $\ln 2$:\\[\medskipamount]
  \begin{enumerate*}[label=\alph*),itemjoin=\tab,resume]
  \item $\ln 4$ 
  \item $\ln \sqrt[3]{2^5}$ 
  \item $\ln \frac{1}{16} $
  \end{enumerate*} 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The \setcounter{enumii}{3} works fine as long as I stay in the upper enumerate-environment. Doesn't work in a new enumerate-inparaenum-environment. But that's ok for the moment. Thank you

Comment: @Mac: This deliberately depends on the nesting of the environments

Comment: @Mac I suggest you to switch to `enumitem`, that's much more powerful than `paralist`.

Answer (score 6):

Another version, using my `assoccnt` package, without the need of remembering the counter value:

The `contenumii` counter is used to store the total value of the `enumii` counter automatically and stored back after `inparaenum`.

*Caveat: It will be incremented each time when another second level enumeration is used*

*Use the `\SuspendCounters` feature from the `assoccnt` package then*

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage{paralist}                                       
\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage{assoccnt}



\newcounter{contenumii}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{enumii}{contenumii}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Working with logarithms}: 

    \NumTabs{3}
    \begin{inparaenum}[a)]
    Calculate the following

    \item $\ln 1 = $ 
    \tab \item $\ln e = $ 
    \tab \item $\ln \frac{1}{e} = $
    \end{inparaenum} 

    Express the following in terms of $\ln 2$: 

    \NumTabs{3}
    \begin{inparaenum}[a)]\setcounter{enumii}{\number\value{contenumii}}
    \item $\ln 4$ 
    \tab \item $\ln \sqrt[3]{2^5}$ 
    \tab \item $\ln \frac{1}{16} $
    \end{inparaenum} 

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Other options: `enumitem` package, with the `resume` option, but this is not as compact as `paralist` (initially, can be changed, perhaps)

Comment: I cannot compile this.. it says assoccnt.sty not found. Somehow not loading the new package. I'm not sure what to do about it. But thanks for the idea :)

Comment: @Mac: No problem at all... but it's on TeXLive and CTAN of course

Comment: That means I have to load it manually? I'm used to let this be done by TexnicCenter. I'm still looking for how to force my editor do this

Comment: @Mac: I don't use those editor stuff like TexnicCenter etc. I update manually all the time (daily!) by invoking tlmgr on a Linux console

Comment: @ChristianHupfer *Daily*?! Why?

Comment: @cfr: To get all the exciting new packages :-P

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a very late answer, but I found this to work for me:

```
% Counter used in continuing lists.
\newcounter{contlist}
% ...
\begin{inparaenum}[(a)]
\item line-item 1
\item line-item 2
\end{inparaenum}
\setcounter{contlist}{\value{enumi}}
% ...
\begin{inparaenum}[(a)]
\setcounter{enumi}{\value{contlist}}
\item line-item 3
\item line-item 4
\end{inparaenum}
```

This works across different styles of enumerations [1, (b), (iii), etc].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The other answers are also applicable to other styles, so how does this add anything new?

Comment: It answers the original question, and doesn't need hand-coding. Nor does it need other styles/environments.