# not showing define colour

Tags: errors, color

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{\bfseries\textbf\textit\underline{Anum Naeem Nagra}}
\author{anaumnagra@gmail.com}
\date{5thjune,2016}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{linkcolor}{rgb}{0.149019,0,0.439215}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begingroup
\let\center\flushleft
\let\endcenter\endflushleft
\maketitle
\endgroup
\end{minipage}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{my pic}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,natwidth=310,natheight=642]{fig1.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\flushright{\rule{3.5cm}{4.5cm}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Muhammad Naeem Nagra
G.T road\\
Street no1\\
Allabad Wazirabad
June 5th 2016 3rd, 2020\\
+92 03009625256
\end{minipage}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.2}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
\section*{Strenght}
\begin{itemize}
\item I am hard working and optimistic
\item Innovative
\item I am strong enough to work in all type of conditions and work load
\end{itemize}
\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    Degree title & year & Total Marks & Obtained Marks \\ 
    \hline 
    B.Ed             & 2015      & 1200     &  987 \\ 
    \hline 
    BS(CS)Hons       & 2010       & 4.0     & 2.75 \\ 
    \hline 
    FSC(pre-Medical) & 2006       & 1100    & 647 \\ 
    \hline 
    Matric           & 2004       & 850     & 637 \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
\section*{Major subjects}
(i)software  Engeeniering(ii)OperatingSystem(iii) C++\\
(iv) Database             (v) Calculus      (vi)Networks\\              
\section*{contact}
https://www.facebook.com/annie.comp\\
https://www.gmail.com/anaumnagra@gmail.com
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What exactly is your question? Please clarify it.

Comment: I am using Miktex 2.9 and texmaker i want to colour my name in green first i come up with a lot of erors Xcolor.sty not found.i want to know what kind of pakages i need to put in my folder so that my code \definecolor may easily run.If any error in defining color please provide exact right code.Moreover I am bad at intalling pakages from Ctan so if u can post pakage folder i can directly place with.texfiles likelipsum.sty...or etc so code may easily run on Miktex.

Comment: Welcome to the community :) TeX-LaTeX can definitely sometimes be frustrating, even for experienced users, but please try not to let that frustration come through. Your original title came across as a little bit whingy

Comment: hmmm seriously opologize reason is beginner

Comment: @user107166 don't worry, we'll get this issue sorted out. In the meantime, your title is made bold twice `\bfseries\textbf` which is unnecessary and in your major subjects section, you've numbered the list manually, and apparently without formatting, which is not the correct approach, try something like [`inparaenum`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237442/start-inparaenum-numeration-with-another-letter-than-a)

Comment: pakage{paralist}\begin{inparaenum} \item \end{inparaenum} is really helpful

Comment: i also solved url{www.facebbok\annie.com}

Comment: instead of using \usepackage{xcolo} we will \usepackage{color} if want to color the name \textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{\underline{Anum Naeem Nagra}} color links can also use \item\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\url{http://google.com}}
 \item\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{\url{http://facebook.com}}

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{color}
\hbadness=10000
%.........................................................%
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{\underline{Anum Naeem Nagra}}
\end{flushleft}


%............................................................%
\begin{flushright}
Address:sialkot,punjab \\
E mail:@gmail.com\\
PHONE:03416160526
\end{flushright}




%..........................................................%
\section*{\underline{summury}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Working on Computer 
\item Learning Different Languages e.g. C, C++, 
\item Book Reading
\end{itemize}
%.........................................................%
\section*{\underline{Education}}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{degree title} &\textbf{passing year}&\textbf{institute}            &\textbf{grade}\\ 
\hline
MSIT         &2011          &PUNJAB UNIVERSITY             &A\\                 
\hline
B.COM        &2009          &PUNJAB UNIVERSITY             &A\\                
 \hline
FSC          &2007         &GOVT COMMERCE COLLEGE          &A\\                                              
\hline
MATRIC       &2005         &FATIMA JINNAH GIRLS SCHOOL     &A\\       
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
%..............................................................%
\section*{\underline{Courses}}
\begin{inparaenum}[\hspace{1em}(i)]
\item Microsoft office
\item Adobe photoshop
\item Adobe auto CAD\\
\item Coral Draw  
\item CCNA 
\item computer courses \\
\end{inparaenum}
%............................................................%
 \section*{\underline{APPROACH ME}}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\url{http://google.com}}
 \item\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{\url{http://facebook.com}}

\end{enumerate}

%.........................................................%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this the answer or should this be an edit to the question?

Comment: \usepackage{color}                                                           \textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{\underline{Anum Naeem Nagra}}      As we are not using modern cv package we can use limited colours with package color.Christin the answer is we may use modern cv but if we are not using modern cv we can use Package color for rgb colours